# Why is Symfony/Git ignoring some of the folders?

Tags: git, symfony, gitignore

I just noticed that when I push my Symfony project to Gitlab, some of the folders (for example "vendor") are not pushed (because they are ignored by .gitignore).

Why is this? And isn't it problematic if I then want to clone the project from Gitlab onto my other computer, where I then would be missing the vendor folder?

Comment: Why are folders that are designated as ignored being ignored? Is that the question?

Comment: Use composer to reinstall the packages, since `composer.lock` is commited, the installation is always repeateable to the same versions.

Comment: @msg How do I install the depencies from composer.lock? What should I write in the terminal?

Comment: Note that Git doesn't push *files*, but rather *commits* (which then contain files). The files contained in any given commit are the files you get when you extract that commit: each commit holds a full archive of every file (well, every file it contains). The files inside the commits are compressed and de-duplicated so it doesn't hurt to re-use all the files over and over: that takes no space at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you don't want to include the vendor folder in git, as that can be rebuilt when you deploy by saving your composer.lock file.

Your deploy should use `composer install` to build the vendor directory, and it will use the same files as those installed by composer in your source commit(s).

**In summary:**

- When changing packages via modifications to the composer.json, run `composer update`.
- Save/commit changes to *composer.lock*
- clones of the repo should run `composer install`
- composer does more than just fetch and install dependencies -- it also runs utility scripts, and differentiates between production and development environments.  It will also build the autoload script for inclusion in your project.
- Running `composer install` can be done whenever you would like, so you can run it everytime you git pull if you want. It should be idempotent with git repos.
- For a production environment [there are options to consider](https://getcomposer.org/doc/) like using the --no-dev flag.  `composer install --no-dev`  This will omit any development libraries, however, it is important to have a staging environment to insure you've actually tested that build somewhere.  You might want to research and consider these additional options for a production deployment:  `composer install --no-dev --no-scripts --optimize-autoloader`.